# How to run same cucumber scenario for multiple regions using tags associated with the scenario

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

**Description of problem**:

I am trying to run same cucumber scenario for multiple regions using cucumber and java.

**What I am trying to achieve?**

1. There are three different regions au, nl and gb associated with my scenario (specified as tags)
2. I want to use all 3 tags to run my scenario one after another

**What I have tried ?**

I am not sure how to achieve same using cucumber. please find below code for reference

```
@au-en @nl-nl @gb-en
Scenario: A new user can place order using ecom sites 
Given the Guest user buying product
Then the user perform checkout 


//step definition cucumber
@Before
public void setUp(Scenario scenario) {
    listTags= (List) scenario.getSourceTagNames();
    listTags
            .stream()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}

 @Given("^the Guest user buying product$") {
 public void buyProduct() {

        for(Object item : listTags) {
        System.out.println("******item*********" + item);

        homepage.navigateToPage(baseUrl.concat(url)); //call url 
        productSelection.selectProduct();
        productSelection.AddTobasket()
        basketPageSteps.clickCheckoutButton();
        }

}

@Then("^the user perform checkout$")
public void theUserIsOnTheCheckoutCompletePage() {
       cheeckoutPage.ClickCheckout();
}
```

Comment: Are there any application behavior differences between regions?

Answer (score 2):

Defining multiple tags next to each other separated by space means that, it's going to execute the scenario whenever either or all them are mentioned in `CucumberOptions` like below:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}, tags = {"@au-en,@nl-nl,@gb-en"}) 

public class runTest { }`
```

Coming back to your requirement, if you want to run the scenario for each of the tags separately, you can follow either of the below method:

1. If the scenario's implementation is supposed to be same for each region, then you can use `Scenario Example`, where for the same scenario you would be parameterising the region details under 'Example' section. Something like this:

   `Scenario Outline: eating`

   `Given there are <start> cucumbers`

   `When I eat <eat> cucumbers`

   `Then I should have <left> cucumbers`

   `Examples:`

   `| start | eat | left |`

   `|    12 |   5 |    7 |`

   `|    20 |   5 |   15 |`
2. If the scenario's implementation is going to be different for each region, then you can define scenarios for each region and have a specific tag attached above the respective region implementation. Now, you can mention these tags in `CucumberOptions` like before in the order you want to call and execute.

Here are some references for Item 1: [https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags] and Item 2: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_tags.htm]

Comment: I dont want to use Scenario Outline , I want to execute my test using tags simulteniously for all regions

Comment: In that case you would have to specify the scenarios once per region and run them in paralllel. The way you are using tags in the example does not work (as explained above).

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options here:

1. Do a Cucumber run for each region
2. Write separate scenarios for each region (this one uses tags)
3. Write a single scenario that tests all 3 regions at the same time

You need to choose the one that best meets your needs.

### 1 Do a Cucumber run for each region

Here you set up external state before the cucumber run so that cucumber can pick the region to use for this particular run.

This would be really useful if you have loads of scenarios you want to run against various regions, and if the application behaves in the same way for each region

### 2 Write separate scenarios for each region

Here you could use tags so you can do things like only run gb-en scenarios in a particular run. You would have something like

```
@gb-en
Scenario: Can buy in GB
  ...

@nl@nl
Scenario: Can buy in the Netherlands
  ...
```

This is a really good way of testing regional behaviour

### 3. Write a single scenario that tests all 3 regions at the same time

This is the one you seem to want, however I don't think you'll want to do what is required.

Here you have to write a scenario like

```
Scenario: Regional buying
  Given the following regions en-gb ...
  When I buy something from each region
  Then I should see I have bought something from each region
```

This one is pretty ugly. Here you have to have a step that buys something for each region, which is going to be pretty complex. The step will have to

- change the region
- buy the product
- save the result

and then repeat that for each region.